# How to deserialize a Laravel Eloquent model, i.e. reverse toArray(), attributesToArray() or toJson()?

Tags: laravel, serialization, eloquent, orm

[Laravel serialization documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization) describes in detail how to get array / JSON representation of Eloquent models.

However, it doesn't currently say a word about reversing this: getting Eloquent models out of arrays / JSON.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's old but if anybody is still looking for it.

Maybe you are trying to do the fill operation.

Eg:

```
$user = [
    'name' => 'Foo Bar',
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
];

$userModel = new User();
$userModel->fill($user);

// If you want to save this then -> $userModel->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! **Important caveat: fill() only works on attributes which are mass-assignable.**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make an instance of your model and affect your data to it, for example, supposer you have a array representation of a User model like this:

```php
$user = [
    "name" => "foo",
    "age" => 40
]
```

then you will have to create your model like this:

```php
$user = User::create($user);

//or

$user = new User;
$user->name = $user["name"];
$user->age  = $user["age"];
$user->save()
```